# After upgrade to macOS Sierra secd is using 98% power and cannot be force quit in Activity Monitor

Tags: install, macos

Fan has ran for 3 days after upgrading my MacBook Air (mid 2011).

Comment: Can you post any logs? If Console.app is acting up the `log stream` command may work...

Comment: Also agreed, this upgrade was a mistake for my 2011 MacbookAir, running between 94-98%. Fans running contantly now....

Comment: See @klanomoath answer.

Comment: I finally solved the problem by starting "Keychain Access", selecting "Preferences..." and clicking "Reset My Default Keychain".  After rebooting secd was no longer taking significant CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this go to the iCloud settings panel and start the process to enable iCloud Keychain, enter a password, but cancel before completing.

Comment: I don't understand this. Enter password where? Before completing what?